# Getting LINQ Exception handling in the query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
var lstgroupCode = (from g in _context.ALM_USER_GROUP_MSTs where g.isShiftAvailable == true select g.User_Group_Code).ToList();

foreach (var item in lstgroupCode)
{
    if (item.User_Group_Code == UserGroupCode)
    {
        btnPlaySuspend.Visible = true;
        lblPlayPause.Visible = true;
        btnStopSuspend.Visible = true;
        lblStop.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnPlaySuspend.Visible = false;
        lblPlayPause.Visible = false;
        btnStopSuspend.Visible = false;
        lblStop.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> item.User_Group_Code as 'string' does not contain a definition for 'User_Group_Code'

What could be the issue?

Comment: You already selected the item of User_Group_Code into a list - so you shouldnt need to split it again, each item in the list is a User_Group_Code unless a User_Group_Code has a property of User_Group_Code - but thats not visible in the code you gave us

Comment: No User_Group_Code doesnt have a property of User_Group_Code. So how can i rewrite this code?

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesnt have the sub property of the same name something like

```
var lstgroupCode = (from g in _context.ALM_USER_GROUP_MSTs where g.isShiftAvailable == true select g.User_Group_Code).ToList();

            foreach (var item in lstgroupCode)
            {
                if (item == UserGroupCode)
                {
                    btnPlaySuspend.Visible = true;
                    lblPlayPause.Visible = true;
                    btnStopSuspend.Visible = true;
                    lblStop.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnPlaySuspend.Visible = false;
                    lblPlayPause.Visible = false;
                    btnStopSuspend.Visible = false;
                    lblStop.Visible = false;
                }
            }
```

Depending on what UserGroupCode is..